# How to add another colour on Cal heat map empty data cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, cal-heatmap

[image: Calender Heat Map Chart]

As shown in image grey colour cells are empty without values but i want to change the colour of that cells is any solution in cal-heatmap library.I have searched something like paint or fill function but those are not related to what i am searchhing for.
Please help me,
Thank you